# Populating select field by given dictionary

Tags: jquery, python, html, flask, wtforms

I found an example which populates the select field by given html strings:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#shape").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $("#size").html(options[val]);
    });

    var options = [
        "<option value='test'>item1: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item1: test 2</option>",
        "<option value='test'>item2: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item2: test 2</option>",
        "<option value='test'>item3: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item3: test 2</option>"
    ];

});
</script>
```

Which works fine but how do I have to change the script to do the same with a given dictionary?

```
options = {
    'ipe': ['80', '100'],
    'hea': ['90', '110'],
}
```

Here a picture to illustrate:
[image]

Here my html snippet:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <table>

<tr>
  <td>{{ form.shape.label }}</td>
  <td>{{ form.shape(class="form-control field", id="shape") }}</td>
  <td>{{ widgets.errors(form.shape.errors) }}</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>{{ form.size.label }}</td>
  <td>{{ form.size(class="form-control field", id="size") }}</td>
  <td>{{ widgets.errors(form.size.errors) }}</td>
</tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"how do I have to change the script to do the same with a given dictionary?"_ What is expected resulting `html` within `#size` ?

Comment: The select field `#shapes` provides all the keys which by selecting should populate the select field `#size`

Comment: Should `#size` be populated with `option` element having value of each item within array of values corresponding to `#shape` value ?

Comment: Yes, `#shape` provides the keys `['ipe', 'hea']` and by selecting i.e `'ipe'` then `#size` should be populated with `['80', '100']`

Comment: _"Yes, #shape provides the keys ['ipe', 'hea'] and by selecting i.e 'ipe' then #size should be populated with ['80', '100']"_ . Can include `html` of `#size` ? Is expected result text `['80', '100']` within `#size` ?, or two `option` elements having value of `"80"` , `"100"` respectively ?

Comment: The expected result should be two option elements having the value `"80"`, `"100"`.

Comment: _"The expected result should be two option elements having the value "80", "100""_ See post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utilizing `Array.prototype.map()` , `Array.prottotype.join()`

```js
var options = {
  "ipe": ["80", "100"],
  "hea": ["90", "110"]
};

$("#shape").change(function() {
  var val = options[this.value];

  $("#size").html(function() {
    return val.map(function(el) {
      return $("<option>", {
        "name": el,
        "value": el,
        "html": el
      })[0].outerHTML
    }).join("");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<label>Shape:
  <select id="shape">
    <option>select an option</option>
    <option name="ipe" value="ipe">ipe</option>
    <option name="hea" value="hea">hea</option>
  </select>
</label>
<label>Size:
  <select id="size">
  </select>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried to implement but get following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: @ericMTR _"tried to implement but get following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"`_ Error returned at `js` at  stacksnippets , above ? Substituted `var val = options[this.value];` for `var val = $(this).val();` ? Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate , reproduce error ?

Comment: @ guest271314 It works perfectly fine if I use your `html` snippet. But won't work with mine. I will shortly update my OP to show the different. I work with wtforms so I can't show it at `jsfiddle` I gess.

Comment: @ guest271314 I substituted `var val = options[this.value]; for var val = $(this).val();` and got following error: `TypeError: val.map is not a function`

Comment: @ericMTR _"substituted var val = options[this.value]; for var val = $(this).val(); and got following error: TypeError: val.map is not a function"_ Can this be reproduced at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net ? `options[this.value]` should return array within `options` . At image at OP , `"IPE"` appear to be uppercase ; do object keys of `options` match case of `option` element values ?

Comment: Found the bug! The keys didn't match indeed. wtform gives only an index of the selection back not the key itself. well thanks again.